# How can I properly parallellize my test suites in TeamCity?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, teamcity

So I have a scenario whereby I have many different test suites.  They are all triggered by a `Create Test Environment` step.  However, these test suites cannot run concurrently on the same environment, as they would interfere with each other.  To alleviate this, I added a shared resource in TeamCity and configured the build definitions to block on this resource, so that only one test suite runs at a time.  This works.

However, if while the test suites for Environment A are running, another code change is checked in, Environment B can be created by the `Create Test Environment` step, and all the test suites are re-queued.  Currently, due to the fact that they all share a shared resource that they block on, those tests then sit in the queue awaiting access to the shared resource.  However, there is no reason that the tests for Environment B cannot run (one build at a time) in parallel with the tests for Environment A.  How can I best tweak my TeamCity configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for Matrix builds. This feature is not implemented in TeamCity. As workaround you can create different build configurations for different environments. You can use TeamCity templates to simplify the setup. For more details see the [related comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3661#comment=27-431092) in the TeamCity issue tracker.